# exec bash script for each item in list

Tags: linux, bash, xargs

I have a text file with URLs

```
http://example.com/1
http://example.com/2
```

etc.

I have a bash script that takes the URL as $1 and works with it.
I would like to automate it and I have tried with

```
cat urls.txt | xargs -P0 bash -c myscript.sh
```

but `$1` comes up as empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use [`read`](http://ss64.com/bash/read.html) with a while loop, here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line      # read a line from file.
do
  echo "$line"
  ./myscript.sh "$line"             # pass a line to the script
done < urls.txt
```

Comment: There is no need for `eval` here.

Comment: @chepner why I need wrap a `$line` variable to the double quotes here? I check it, and it works without double quotes.

Comment: @Зелёный my urls dont have spaces in them but i assume its for good practice

Comment: It's not just spaces. Unquoted expansions are also subject to pathname expansion. The default is to treat a pattern that doesn't match as literal text, but it's still good practice to quote parameter expansions unless there is a good reason not to.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `-c` (or `cat`):

```
xargs -P0 bash myscript.sh < urls.txt
```

---

`-c` takes a string argument to use as the command, for example,

```
$ bash -c 'echo foo'
foo
```

When using `-c`, the next argument after the command string is used as the value for `$0`, not `$1`:

```
$ bash -c 'echo Command: $0; echo Arg: $1' zeroth first
Command: zeroth
Arg: first
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel it looks like this:

```
cat urls.txt | parallel -j0 ./myscript.sh
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. It can often replace a `for` loop.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel